# SIP Timers: What is use of TimerC in SIP?

Tags: sip, sip-server, opensips

RFC-3261 doesn't talk much about TimerC and when it fires.
I understand the importance of TimerC in forking scenarios.

Does TimerC have any role in regular SIP call?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Only Proxies use Timer C. Timer C is the proxy INVITE transaction timeout.
It is used to check if a proxied INVITE request never generates a final response. The Timer C MUST be set for each client transaction when an INVITE request is proxied ie each URI you forward the SIP INVITE to after receiving the initial INVITE.